# to change the path of the file

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to use fileupload tag to upload a file. What it basically does is, it saves the file into the follwoing directory:

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\10.0\
```

Can someone please tell me how to change this path and save the upload file into some other directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the complete control of this. If you want to the file saved to a different path, then use this :

```
fileUpload.PostedFile.SaveAs("c:\my path\" + fileUpload.FileName);
```

Make sure it (folder) has permissions

Answer (score 1):

```
FileUpload1.SaveAs(savePath);
```

read more about [FileUpload.SaveAs Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.saveas.aspx)